# More memory and velocity efficient way to read in and save images?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I am training a neural network. Therefore, I read in 182335 images (png-files) with the code below.

```
folders = glob.glob(r'path\to\images\*')
imagenames_list = []
for folder in folders:
    for f in glob.glob(folder+'/*.png'):
        imagenames_list.append(f)
read_images = []        

for image in imagenames_list:
    read_images.append(cv2.imread(image))
```

After some preprocessing of the data I created a pandas dataframe and saved it as a pickle-file:

```
df.to_pickle(r'data\data_as_pddataframe.pkl')

df.head()
```

[image: headers]

Because of the huge number of images I have a relatively big pickle file (3GB). Because of this it lasts some time to read in this file and it also needs a lot of memory. Furthermore, when I am going to train the network in Google Colab, it happens that Colab crashes because of the huge amount of data.

Therefore, is there a more efficient way 1. to read in the data and 2. to store the dataframe?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the data being stored inside the DataFrame?

Comment: If nothing else, you should not use Pickle as your data format. Consider using Parquet or HDF5. See https://realpython.com/storing-images-in-python/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I edited my question. There is also some more data stored in the dataframe. The variables are image, the image_path, track_id, lp and train.

Comment: OK. As for the crashing Colab, surely you are running your model with SGD or batch SGD, right? Then all you have to do is store the data on disk somewhere and load records one at a time (or in batches) for training.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I am training on batch SGD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

1. Make sure that the batch size of your model is small enough that the input data and model parameters fit in memory.
2. Save the images as images on disk. Save the non-image data as a Parquet, CSV, or whatever (don't use Pickle for this). Put the image filenames in the table.
3. Keep data on disk, don't load it all into memory.
4. Load your non-image data as a regular data frame. Only load images from disk when it's required for your batch in SGD.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I am wondering how to separate the training from the test data without merging the images with the other data, because test and training data are stored in the same folders. In this other data there is stated which data are the training data and which are the test data.

Comment: The data frame should say which image file to use for each record, so as long as you have two different data frames for training and testing, it shouldn't be a problem to keep all the images in one directory.

Comment: Ok, so that means you would replace the column image against a cloumn image_names, is that correct? In order to do so I could put the imagenames_list's items in the table with all the other data (image_path, track_id etc.)? I have still some troubles with getting images to disk and only using them batchwise..

Comment: @Tobitor something like that, yes. I have no used Google Colab so I can't comment on whether there are specific difficulties getting this kind of configuration to work in that environment.